# How to ORDER a LEFT JOIN for 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sorting

I've (on reflection ridiculously) stored our 'punters' in 2 tables depending on whether they registered or paid through the express checkout form.

My SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT(sale_id), sale_punter_type, sale_comment, sale_refund, sale_timestamp, 
    punter_surname, punter_firstname, 
    punter_checkout_surname, punter_checkout_firstname,
    punter_compo_surname, punter_compo_firstname, 
    sale_random, sale_scanned, sale_id 
FROM 
    sale 
LEFT JOIN 
    punter ON punter_id = sale_punter_no 
LEFT JOIN 
    punter_checkout ON punter_checkout_id = sale_punter_no 
LEFT JOIN 
    punter_compo ON punter_compo_id = sale_punter_no 
WHERE 
    sale_event_no = :id
ORDER BY 
    punter_surname, punter_firstname, 
    punter_checkout_surname, punter_checkout_firstname
```

It returns results BUT lists the registered users alphabetically first, then the checkout punters alphabetically.

My question is there a way to get all of the users (registered or checkout) all together sorted alphabetically in 1 sorted list instead of 2 joined sorted lists.

I thought maybe I could use something like punter_checkout_surname AS punter_surname but that didn't work.

Any thoughts? I know now that I shouldn't have used 2 separate tables but but I'm stuck with it now.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you have parentheses around the  `saleid`?  Are you confusing `SELECT DISTINCT` with some function that takes an argument?

Comment: Note that DISTINCT applies to all columns which follow it in the column list; therefore in this case you're getting the unique combinations of `sale_id`, `sale_punter_type`, `sale_comment`, `sale_refund`, `sale_timestamp`, 
`punter_surname`, `punter_firstname`, `punter_checkout_surname`, `punter_checkout_firstname`, `punter_compo_surname`, `punter_compo_firstname`, `sale_random`, `sale_scanned`, and `sale_id`. This may not be what you had in mind.

Comment: Thank you Bob, that makes sense - I did not know that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my answer:

```
ORDER BY 
    COALESCE( UCASE( punter_surname) , UCASE( punter_checkout_surname ), UCASE( punter_compo_surname ) ) , 
    COALESCE( UCASE( punter_firstname ) , UCASE( punter_checkout_firstname ), UCASE( punter_compo_firstname) )
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to use `coalesce()`.

```
ORDER BY COALESCE(punter_surname, punter_checkout_surname)
         COALESCE(punter_firstname, punter_checkout_firstname)
```

Other comments:

- I doubt that `DISTINCT` is necessary.  Why would this generate multiple rows for a single `sale_id`?
- When a query has multiple tables, qualify all the column names (that is, include table aliases so you and others know where the table comes from).
- Your data has three sets of names.  That seems overkill.
- You might want to put the `COALESCE()` in the `SELECT` so you don't have quite so many names generated by the query.

Comment: I have removed DISTINCT, you are right, it was unnecessary 
.
COALESCE didn't work, it returned less records than I was expecting. I've read about COALESCE but still don't understand it particularly & definitely don't understand how it would help me with this problem.  Initially I thought it would concatenate my results but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: Sorry I doubted you.  it did work but I had to make some of it UCASE to get it to work properly.